# Use ssh key for Spring Boot Remote ssh shell

Tags: spring, ssh, spring-boot, ssh-keys

When using the [Spring Boot Remote SSH shell](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-remote-shell.html) is it somehow possible to add public ssh keys to the application's configuration (e.g. via `application.properties`) so that authentication to the ssh console uses public / private key authentication?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `shell.ssh.key-path` property in `application.properties` to configure the path to your key file.

Comment: since my application is running in a cloud environment this won't help me since I have no file system available... anyways thx for the hint

Comment: AFAIK, CRaSH requires the key to be available from a file on the filesystem. See http://www.crashub.org/1.3/reference.html#_key_authentication for details. Boot maps the `shell.ssh.key-path` property onto `crash.auth.key.path`. Anything more sophisticated would require you to write your own authentication plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
management.shell.auth.type=key
management.shell.auth.key.path=xxx
```

if you read the source code, you will get the above result :)

Comment: also,you need a key path like this: